# How to disable global Linum mode for certain mode?

Tags: init-file, hooks, linum-mode, term

in my `init.el` file I have the following:

```
(global-linum-mode 1)
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode)))
```

However, when I enter `ansi-term-mode` linum mode is still on.

I have also tried

```
(add-hook 'ansi-term-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode)))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode nil)))
```

Does anyone have any idea how to turn off linum mode for ansi-term-mode only?

Comment: Did you try `(linum-mode -1)` ?

Comment: @YoungFrog yes to no avail.

Comment: @Startec Just to be clear, you need to have `(global-linum-mode 1) (add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode -1)))`, then **restart** emacs to see the effect. Note the **-1**.

Comment: This question gets asked over and over, with the description and title being about the specific mode. **Someone (TM)** please edit this to replace it by a (Community) generic question that is posed as is the SO duplicate [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the duplicate question on StackOverflow:

[automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode)

---

*This was converted to a comment when it's a perfectly sensible answer (seeing as how we can't close for duplication across SE sites), so this text is just to prevent that from happening...*

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```el
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (linum-mode
              (if (-contains?
               '(text-mode
                 term-mode
                 help-mode
                 doc-view-mode)
               0 1)))))
```