# term without line numbers and highlight for current line

Tags: minor-mode, term, linum-mode, hl-line-mode

I have the following settings in ~/.emacs:

```
(setq linum-relative-current-symbol "")
(linum-mode)
(linum-relative-global-mode)
(global-hl-line-mode t)
```

In order to supress both these features in terminal, I added the following to ~/.emacs:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-line-mode -1)))
```

Now when I M-x term RET /bin/zsh RET, it produces an unusable terminal. See the image below:

[image: terminal image]

As you can see, it still uses line numbers and highlights the current line.

What am I doing wrong? How do I set things right?

Comment: For anyone who is wondering about the variable `linum-relative-current-symbol` which is not included with a base installation of Emacs, here is a link to the library that the OP is likely using:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/linum-relative.el  It loads the built-in `linum.el` library, which the OP probably has enabled globally.  The question is really about how to make the built-in global `linum-mode` buffer-local, or turn off `linum-mode` (enabled globally) for `term-mode` buffers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable global Linum mode for certain mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17333/how-to-disable-global-linum-mode-for-certain-mode)  For `hl-line-mode`, see also:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4nq20t/how_do_i_turn_off_current_line_highlighting_when/?st=jacv0nxr&sh=cbb38dbe

Comment: See also the duplicate question on StackOverflow as to `hl-line-mode` entitled "**how to disable hl-line feature in specified mode**":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990370/how-to-disable-hl-line-feature-in-specified-mode