# How to disable show-trailing-whitespace in emacs shell?

Tags: whitespace, shell-mode

[image]

I have set show-trailing-whitespace as default in my .emacs file but I don't want it to work on shell and some specific buffer. I can disable it manually every time I open an emacs shell but I want more of a permanent solution. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable global Linum mode for certain mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17333/how-to-disable-global-linum-mode-for-certain-mode)

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a dup, since this is about a variable and not a mode. But it's very similar. It would be good to have a single Community Q&A that covers the general idea (i.e., covers both variables and modes).

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that you'll want to do this for numerous modes, so I would suggest using an approach which makes that simpler to specify. e.g.:

```el
(defun my-hide-trailing-whitespace-maybe ()
  "Disable `show-trailing-whitespace' in selected modes."
  (when (derived-mode-p 'shell-mode
                        'some-other-mode
                        '...)
    (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          'my-hide-trailing-whitespace-maybe)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in your init-file:

```el
 (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

That disables `show-trailing-whitespace` locally in shell buffers.
Change `shell-mode-hook` to any major mode hook you want if you like to disable `show-trailing-whitespace` also in other modes.